# How do I specify the user for a test database (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, database

I want to set up my test and development databases with different users.  My `database.yml` file looks like this:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: test_db
  username: test_user
  password: test_pass
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: dev_db
  username: dev_user
  password: devpass
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

I normally develop using Sinatra and so am used to creating my databases and users manually before using `rake` tasks to run migrations etc. But for this project I am using Rails and I can't figure out how to tell Rails' `db:test:prepare` task to create the databases using the users I have specified. It all works if I just run `db:migrate` - the dev database I created manually gets set up fine, but when I try to run my tests the rake tasks fall over at the `db:test:prepare` task.

How do I configure Rails 4 to use the database users I want rather than `root` or some other default?

Comment: Does test_user exist? What's the error you get at the `db:test:prepare` step?

Answer (score 0):

You could try rebuilding them from scratch with:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```